# What is wrong with this mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this mysql trigger?
I am unable to understand what is actually going wrong.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `task_completion` after UPDATE
ON `inhouse_session_tasks` FOR each row 
   BEGIN

      SET @total = (
                    SELECT
                           COUNT(ist.id) 
                    FROM
                          `inhouse_session_tasks` ist 
                    LEFT JOIN
                          `inhouse_sessions` iss 
                          ON iss.id = NEW.session_id 
                    LEFT JOIN
                          `inhouse_batches` ib 
                          ON ib.id = iss.batch_id 
                    LEFT JOIN
                          `inhouse_process` ip 
                          ON ip.id = ib.process_id 
                    WHERE
                          ip.id = ib.process_id
                   );

    SET @completed = (
                      SELECT
                              COUNT(ist.id) 
                      FROM
                              `inhouse_session_tasks` ist 
                      LEFT JOIN
                              `inhouse_sessions` iss 
                              ON iss.id = NEW.session_id 
                      LEFT JOIN
                              `inhouse_batches` ib 
                              ON ib.id = iss.batch_id 
                      LEFT JOIN
                              `inhouse_process` ip 
                              ON ip.id = ib.process_id 
                      WHERE
                              ip.id = ib.process_id 
                              AND ist.status = 1
                     );

    set @average = (
                    @completed *100 / @total
                   );

    update
           `inhouse_process` 
    SET
           `process` = @average 
    WHERE
           1;
```

Error:

> The following query has failed: "CREATE TRIGGER `task_completion` AFTER UPDATE ON `inhouse_session_tasks` FOR EACH ROW CREATE TRIGGER `task_completion` after UPDATE ON `inhouse_session_tasks` FOR each row BEGIN SET @total = ( SELECT COUNT(ist.id) FROM `inhouse_session_tasks` ist LEFT JOIN `inhouse_sessions` iss ON iss.id = NEW.session_id LEFT JOIN `inhouse_batches` ib ON ib.id = iss.batch_id LEFT JOIN `inhouse_process` ip ON ip.id = ib.process_id WHERE ip.id = ib.process_id ); SET @completed = ( SELECT COUNT(ist.id) FROM `inhouse_session_tasks` ist LEFT JOIN `inhouse_sessions` iss ON iss.id = NEW.session_id LEFT JOIN `inhouse_batches` ib ON ib.id = iss.batch_id LEFT JOIN `inhouse_process` ip ON ip.id = ib.process_id WHERE ip.id = ib.process_id AND ist.status = 1 ); set @average = ( @completed *100 / @total ); update `inhouse_process` SET `process` = @average WHERE 1;"
>
> MySQL said: #1303 - Can't create a TRIGGER from within another stored routine

Comment: What statement terminator are you using? As a side note, you can optimize @total and @completed calculation as `COUNT(ist.id) as total, COUNT(case when ist.status = 1 then 1 end) as completed`

Comment: @Lennart i want both of them to get how much process is completed.

Comment: Does `inhouse_process` table have a single row?

Comment: @Ashish Patel, you can determine both values at the same time. In fact, you can do the update without a single variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the real problem is solved I'll just add a simplified body:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER task_completion 
AFTER UPDATE ON inhouse_session_tasks 
FOR each row 
BEGIN
    UPDATE inhouse_process 
        SET process = ( 
           SELECT 100*COUNT(case when ist.status = 1 then 1 end) / COUNT(1)
           FROM inhouse_session_tasks ist 
           LEFT JOIN inhouse_sessions iss 
               ON iss.id = NEW.session_id 
           LEFT JOIN inhouse_batches ib 
               ON ib.id = iss.batch_id 
           LEFT JOIN inhouse_process ip 
               ON ip.id = ib.process_id 
           WHERE ip.id = ib.process_id 
       )
    WHERE ...;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing `END` to the end of your query.